# Продолжить цикл с начала

Tags: python

Как начать/продолжить цикл(следующие значения i,j). “Input=AaaassDffReerh”

```
a,new=list(input()),[]
t=1
for i in a:
    for j in a[1:]:
        if i==j:
            while i==j:
                t+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

В какой-то момент Ваш цикл while становится бесконечным `while True`.

```py
a,new=list("AaaassDffReerh"),[]
print(a[1:])
t=1
for i in a:
    for j in a[1:]:
        if i==j:
            while i==j:
                t+=1
                break # позволит прервать цикл
```

P.S. Опишите Вашу задачу. Есть мысль это можно сделать немного поудачнее.

Через словарь:

```py
a = "AaaassDffReerh"
dic = {}

for i in a:
    if i not in dic:
        dic[i] = 1 # создаем новый ключ
    else:
        dic[i] += 1 # увеличиваем значение на 1

s = []
for i in dic:
    if dic.get(i) <= 1:
        s+= i
    else:
        s+=(str(dic.get(i)) + i)

print(''.join(s))
```

Comment: Надо посчитать кол-во повторов, т.е. из этой строки надо получить “A3a2sD2fR2erh”

Comment: @Виталий Добавил вариант. Далее со словарем уже можно объединить значения в любом виде.

Comment: в else можно написать просто `dic[i] += 1` т.к. вы точно знаете что там есть значение

Comment: @Danis дополнил спасибо )

Comment: Спасибо, но я со словорями пока не очень дружу вариант вывода не тот получается {'A': 1, 'a': 3, 's': 2, 'D': 1, 'f': 2, 'R': 1, 'e': 2, 'r': 1, 'h': 1} Сначала цифра нужна, потом буква, а если буква одна то цифры 1 не должно быть

Comment: @Виталий Там в цикле все собирается под любой формат ) дополнил ответ

Comment: Странно, с этим набором букв все правильно, а с этим « aaabccccCCaB»  получается « 4ab4c2CB» а должно быть « 3ab4c2CaB» в начале лишняя «а» а предпоследнюю пропустил

Comment: @Виталий логично что так получается так как в коде у Вас 4 буквы a. В данном случае подсчитывается общее количество букв и выводится в порядке в котором они встречаются первый раз. т.е. "aabbaa"  = 4a2b

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но надо чтобы было “2a2b2a”, решил через циклы всетаки)

Answer (score 0):

Так должно работать?

```
text = list(input())

text += chr(ord(text[len(text) - 1]) + 1)

result = ''
now_char = text[0]
count = 1

for i in range(1, len(text)):
    if text[i] == now_char:
        count += 1
    else:
        if count == 1:
            result += now_char
        else:
            result += str(count) + now_char
        now_char = text[i]
        count = 1

print(result)
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score -1):

```
a,new,t,u=list(input()),[],1,0
while u<len(a):
    if u+1!=len(a) and a[u]==a[u+1]:
        while a[u]==a[u+1]:
            u+=1
            t+=1
            if u+1==len(a):
                break
        new.append(t)
        new.append(a[u])
        t=1
    else:
        new.append(a[u])
    u+=1
print(*new,sep="")
```